# How to convert launch file ros1 to ros2

Tags: ubuntu, ros, launch, ros2, rviz

I have the following launch file written in XML format working fine in ros1 noetic I am not able to launch it in ros2.

```
<launch>
  <arg
    name="model" />
  <param
    name="robot_description"
    textfile="$(find mobile_robot)/urdf/mobile_robot.urdf" />
  <node
    name="joint_state_publisher_gui"
    pkg="joint_state_publisher_gui"
    type="joint_state_publisher_gui" />
  <node
    name="robot_state_publisher"
    pkg="robot_state_publisher"
    type="robot_state_publisher" />
  <node
    name="rviz"
    pkg="rviz"
    type="rviz"
    args="-d $(find mobile_robot)/urdf.rviz" />
</launch>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [official documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Launch-files-migration-guide.html#migrating-tags-from-ros-1-to-ros-2) for converting launch files. The tl;dr version is that the `type` tag has been changed to `exec`, `ns` to `namespace`. There is also no global params, and the `textfile` param type has been removed(both are relevant to your code). And finally, `rviz` is not a ros2 package; it's now `rviz2`.

I'd also suggest working on the formatting of your launch files for future posts, this doesn't follow the ros formatting standards and is fairly hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this,

```py
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time', default='true')
    urdf = os.path.join(
    get_package_share_directory('mobile_robot'),
    'urdf',
    'mobile_robot.urdf')
    
    rviz = os.path.join(
    get_package_share_directory('mobile_robot'), 'urdf.rviz')          
    return LaunchDescription([
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
                os.path.join(pkg_gazebo_ros, 'launch', 'gzserver.launch.py')
            ),
            launch_arguments={'world': world}.items(),
        ),

        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
                os.path.join(pkg_gazebo_ros, 'launch', 'gzclient.launch.py')
            ),
        ),
        
        Node(
            package='robot_state_publisher',
            executable='robot_state_publisher',
            name='robot_state_publisher',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}],
            arguments=[urdf]),
        
        Node(
            package='rviz2',
            executable='rviz2',
            name='rviz2',
            arguments=['-d', rviz],
            output='screen'),
    ])
```